# Can angular polyfills.ts file be safely removed

Tags: angular, polyfills

Now that angular is working with Ivy and decided to abandon internet explorer.

Shall we safely remove the `polyfills.ts` file in our Angular `>= v13` project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Angular <=14

According to the [docs](https://v14.angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills-with-cli-projects), Angular has a mandatory polyfill for `zone.js`. Without this polyfill, your application may not work. So it is not safe to remove the `polyfills.ts` file.

### Angular 15

Apparently, in Angular v15 the `polyfills.ts` file is not anymore being added to new projects when using the `ng new` command, see the [updated docs](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#enabling-polyfills-with-cli-projects). So after updating to Angular 15, you may be able to remove the `polyfills.ts` file, if it only contains the `zone.js` import. However, in this case you will need to add the polyfill via `angular.json`:

`"polyfills": ["zone.js"]`

### Angular 17+

Angular 17 introduces support for Signals. As of February 2024, they are integrating Signals into components. According to the [Signals RFC](https://github.com/angular/angular/discussions/49682), components will be able to switch to Signals change detections, which works without zone.js. Applications with only Signal-based components will work without the zone.js polyfill. However, Angular still needs to implement some things to make it work.

Comment: but if you were to load zone outside of the polyfill.ts file or not be dependent on zone.js at all it could be omitted

Comment: Yeah, you can just swap `"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts"` for `"polyfills": ["zone.js"]`

Comment: import path is now zone.js instead of zone.js/dist/zone